# Visual Studios "extra" build files

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

I am looking to create a "Publish" configuration for my VS solution that will build the project and only include the files I actually wish to distribute.

I have switched off `Enable the Visual Studios hosting process` and set the `Debug info` in `Advanced Build Settings` to `none`.

I am trying to stop all the extra XML files and Source Browser Database files that come with the nuGet packages from getting copied to the publish directory (I assume these aren't required) - anyone know how?

Is there anything else that I should be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used a post build event to delete the files that I didn't want.